# Restrict email address to only one domain

Tags: regex, domain-name, email-address

I'm currently using below regex to check emails,

`\w+@\w+\.\w+`

but I would like to force the user to use their school domain (mark@college.edu), how do I accomplish this?

Comment: Try changing the last `\\w+` to `edu`...

Comment: Do you mean only one domain name or of similar type ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific college name, let's suppose it as `college` then validation is pretty easy. Following regex does that.

**Regex:** `[\w0-9\.-]*@college\.edu`

**Explanation:**

- `[\w0-9\.-]*` matches the first part of the `email` which might contain Latin alphanumeric characters, dot, underscore. `-` hyphen should be added either at beginning or end of character class.
- `@college\.edu` checks for the **specific** college's domain name.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mE4vR7/3)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks for the help. If the email address contains a hyphen (ex. m-example@college.edu) would this be correct ? [-\w0-9\.]*@college\.edu

Comment: Yes ! absolutely. Just take precaution to add `-` at beginning or end of regex. Since you didn't mentioned `-` in your question I didn't added it.